# ¿Qué framework de seguridad java puedo utilizar en mi proyecto?

Tags: java

Necesito crear una aplicación web corporativa en la cual accederán empleados y clientes. Necesitaré de roles, permisos y, utilzar JSF y JPA para agilizar la construcción. Entre esto utilizar frameworks como omnifaces, por lo tanto se requiere utilizar CDI.

He estado leyendo sobre algunos frameworks de seguridad como Apache Shiro, Spring Security, Picketlink, Keycloak y OACC y entre estos he encontrado lo siguiente:

- Apache Shiro: hay muy buena información en la red y su aplicación resulta bastante simple y es basicamente lo que necesito ya que permite establecer roles y permisos. No tiene soporte para CDI ni JSF.
- Spring Security: solo lo he probado con spring mvc y jsp. Actualmente no incluye permisos por lo que habria que implementar esa parte. Su configuración y compactibilidad con JavaEE es cosa compleja. No hay mucha información en internet respecto a la integración con jsf, aunque spring provee un tutorial pero este incluye mvc.
- PicketLink: realmente muy poca la información que se pueda encontrar sobre este. Principalmente la que provee jboss pero aun no es suficiente. Es complejo de configurar debido a que incluye compactibilidad con CDI y JPA (que es lo que necesito). Maneja permisos. Su configuración me ha resultado bastante compleja aun sin exito de verlo funcionar con JPA.

  - Keycloak y OACC, estos dos ultimos no me llaman la atención, pues Keycloak es un servidor independiente y de OACC no hay información en la web.

Normalmente que framework de seguridad utilizan en sus proyectos? JAAS parece demasiado estatico y tampoco incluye de forma nativa permisos.